# MySQL set a variable inside CTE: "select" is fine but "set" doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression, local-variables

People say CTE is a view and you can't set a variable in CTE.
But I successfully set a variable @ttl in CTE running the query below:

```
with CTE as (select @ttl:=(select sum(num) from test))
```

And when I run this, which I thought just another way to set a variable, I got an error:

```
with CTE as (set @ttl=(select sum(num) from test))
```

I'm very confused. What exactly is doable and what is not in terms of setting a variable in CTE?

Comment: Could you say _why_ you are trying to set a variable in a with clause?  Show more of what you are actually trying to do?  It seems very likely to me that you will get good advice for a better approach to whatever it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What goes in the parentheses is a subquery; subqueries are always SELECT statements.

[https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html)

```
with_clause:
    WITH [RECURSIVE]
        cte_name [(col_name [, col_name] ...)] AS (subquery)
        [, cte_name [(col_name [, col_name] ...)] AS (subquery)] ...
```

[https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html)

> A subquery is a SELECT statement within another statement.

Note that mysql has deprecated setting variables anywhere other than in a SET statement, so in a future version, expect even your first CTE to give an error.

[https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html)

> Previous releases of MySQL made it possible to assign a value to a user variable in statements other than SET. This functionality is supported in MySQL 8.0 for backward compatibility but is subject to removal in a future release of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer from @ysth, you can use `INTO` to assign an expression in the select-list to a variable:

```
mysql> insert into test set num=42;

mysql> with cte as (select sum(num) as num from test) 
       select num into @ttl from cte;

mysql> select @ttl;
+------+
| @ttl |
+------+
|   42 |
+------+
```

Notice that the `INTO` must be in the outer query. If you try to use it inside a subquery, you get this error:

```
mysql> with cte as (select sum(num) into @ttl from test) 
       select * from cte;
ERROR 3954 (HY000): Misplaced INTO clause, INTO is not allowed inside subqueries, 
and must be placed at end of UNION clauses.
```

I assume the `INTO` syntax will continue to be legal even in future versions of MySQL, after the side-effect assignment with `:=` causes an error.